# Opening TOPCAT through command line Via Python Script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to incorporate the program TOPCAT (which has really amazing plotting capabilities) into a python script I have written. The problem is that when I make a call to the program it tells me:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here's some background to the problem:

1) The way I usually open up topcat through the command line is through the alias I have created:

```
alias topcat='java -jar /home/username/topcat/topcat-full.jar'
```

2) If I'd like to open TOPCAT with a file in mind (let's use a csv file since that's what I'd like it to work with), I would type this into the command line:

```
topcat -f csv /home/username/path_to_csv_file/file.csv
```

And that also works just fine. The problem comes about when I try to call these commands while in my python script. I've tried both subprocess.call and os.system, and they don't seem to know of the existence of the topcat alias for some reason. Even doing a simple call like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['topcat'])
```

doesn't work... However, I can get topcat to open if I run this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java','-jar','/home/username/topcat/topcat-full.jar'])
```

The problem with this is that it simply opens the program, and doesn't allow for me to tell it which file to take in and what type it happens to be.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing incorrectly here? I've also looked into the `shell=True` option and it doesn't seem to be doing any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - so I'm really excited that figured it out. What worked before was:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java','-jar','/home/username/topcat/topcat-full.jar'])
```

It turns out it can take more command line arguments. This is what eventually got it open up with the correct comma separated file through the command line:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java','-jar','/home/username/topcat/topcat-full.jar','-f','csv','/full/path/to/data.csv'])
```

Hopefully this is enough information to help other people who come across this specific task.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this, pystilts might be of interest.

https://github.com/njcuk9999/pystilts

edit: It is a native Python wrapper of Topcat/STILTS.

Comment: try to provide a short note about your answer. so that it can reach every one. link wont help instantly

Comment: This just executes a subprocess and (though usefully and cleverly) returns values to python variables.